# UI Testing UITableView cell count

Tags: ios, uitableview, automated-tests, tdd, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to verify that a table view has been filled with a certain number of cells in my UI test. Here is my code:

```
XCUIApplication().tables.element.swipeUp()
let count = XCUIApplication().tables.element.children(matching: .cell).count
XCTAssert(count > 0)
```

The assert fails because the `count` is always 0, even though the swipe up scrolls the obviously successfully filled table view. I have also tried:

```
XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.count > 0)
```

with the same results. I even created an empty project with a table view with 3 static cells, in just one screen, to remove any other possible distractions for the UI test, and it still always returns 0. I'm testing on iOS 11 with Xcode 9.

Comment: Just an silly guess... Try visibleCells instead of cells?

Comment: visibleCells is not a valid property on the XCUIElementQuery returned by app.tables.

Comment: You should add breakpoint to line that starts with `let count = ...`. Then, run your test, wait for breakpoint to activate and then in bottom section where all the output is being shown type `po app`. This should give you view hierarchy where you can check whether you have your table there. You can post results of view hierarchy here (by editing question).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cells don't always register as cells, depending on how you have your accessibility configured. Double check that accessibility is actually seeing cells in `Xcode menu -> Open Developer Tool -> Accessibility Inspector`.

It's likely what accessibility is seeing is `staticTexts` instead of `cells`, depending on your layout code -- in that case, you should assert

```
XCTAssert(app.tables.staticTexts.count > 0)
```

If you want cells, configure your cells like so in `tableView:cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.isAccessibilityElement = true
cell.accessibilityLabel = cell.titleLabel.text // (for example)
cell.accessibilityIdentifier = "MyCellId" // (or whatever you want XCUITest to identify it as)
```

This will mark the cell as the root accessible item, rather than each of the cell's subviews being discrete elements.

Comment: I've been using `app.tables.cells.count` for a long time, and just recently it intermittently stopped working. `cell.isAccessibilityElement = true` has fixed it for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
XCUIApplication().tables.children(matching: .cell).count
```

Deletes all rows from the table view. Written using Xcode 11.1 and tested using SwiftUI.

```
func deleteAllCellsFromTable() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let tablesQuery = app.tables

    app.navigationBars["Navigation Bar Title"].buttons["Edit"].tap()

    while app.tables.children(matching: .cell).count > 0 {
        let deleteButton = tablesQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).buttons["Delete "]
        deleteButton.tap()

        let deleteButton2 = tablesQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).buttons["trailing0"]
        deleteButton2.tap()
    }
}
```